# Errors in powershell script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I need some help with one script. I don't know anything about scripting at all, I found this script on the internet, but when I run it, errors pop up. Can someone please advise me on where is the problem?

Here is the script:

```
$remoteport = bash.exe -c "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '"
$found = $remoteport -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}';

if( $found ){
  $remoteport = $matches[0];
} else{
  echo "The Script Exited, the ip address of WSL 2 cannot be found";
  exit;
}

#[Ports]

#All the ports you want to forward separated by coma
$ports=@(81,80,433,443,10000,3000,5000,50000-55000);


#[Static ip]
#You can change the addr to your ip config to listen to a specific address
$addr='192.168.100.3';
$ports_a = $ports -join ",";


#Remove Firewall Exception Rules
iex "Remove-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' ";

#adding Exception Rules for inbound and outbound Rules
iex "New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' -Direction Outbound -LocalPort $ports_a -Action Allow -Protocol TCP";
iex "New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2 Firewall Unlock' -Direction Inbound -LocalPort $ports_a -Action Allow -Protocol TCP";

for( $i = 0; $i -lt $ports.length; $i++ ){
  $port = $ports[$i];
  iex "netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr";
  iex "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=$port listenaddress=$addr connectport=$port connectaddress=$remoteport";
}
```

And here is the errors:
[image]
[image: Errors for this script]

Comment: Your picture is blank.   Try typing first command "$remoteport" with no match and see if you have remote connections.  Best way of debugging is finding first error and fix.  You may have typo error, commands that return null (then later commands will fail) or missing cmdlets.

Comment: First error: in the array definition for $ports you do `50000-55000`. You cannot add a range like that and it will be seen as arithmatic: 50000 minus 55000. The other errors are pretty self-explanatory. You are missing a value for the `LocalPort` which comes from error 1. Also, you don't need `iex` (alias for `Invoke-Expression`), so remove those and also the quotes around the actual commands. Plus, in PowerShell you do not need to cose each line with a semi-colon `;`. Your script starts with matching an undefined variable `$remoteport` to something..

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: Do you mean `$ports=@(81,80,433,443,10000,3000,5000) + @(50000..55000);`?